# Is there a standard name for this Generalized logarithm construction

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, definition, functional-equations

Consider the functional equation (for $f: \mathbb{C} - 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{C},  (c,x) \in \mathbb{C}^2 $)

$$ f(cx) = f(x) + 1 $$

The "standard solution to this is the logarithm $\log_c(x)$  (although there's an infinite family of additional solutions that we wont concern ourselves with right away).

I now decided to consider the following two parameter

$$ f(ax + b) = f(x) + 1 $$

I define $\text{glog}_{a,b}(x)$ as the solution to it  ("**G**eneralized-**Log**arithm), i.e.

$$ \text{glog}_{a,b} (ax + b) = \text{glog}(x) + 1  $$

I feel pretty certain someone has defined this function before me, and studied its properties (maybe even defined it as a taylor series for suitable choice of a,b). Does anyone know what it might be called in the standard literature/where to find it?

Comment: For $a>1$, a solution appears to be $\operatorname{glox}_{a,b}(x) = c+\frac{\log\left(x+\frac{b}{a-1}\right)}{\log\left(a\right)}$ for some constant $c$. I'd imagine this is the canonical solution to the equation, though one would have to show no other continuous families of solutions exist (eg via the Cauchy Functional Equation)

Comment: Let $\,g(x) = f\left(x - \frac{b}{a-1}\right)\,$, then $\,f(ax+b)=f(x)+1$ $\iff g(ax)=g(x)+1\,$ and the problem reduces to the previous case.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen you should still post this as an answer so i can accept it. Its some points for you and helps the next person reading this question to be slightly lazier (so they don't have to read the comments)